# OLS estimator through matrix operations

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, least-squares, estimation

The OLS estimator is

$$\hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$$

And I don't know why we have to even think about minimizing squares of residuals and partial derivatives (e.g.,: [https://web.stanford.edu/~mrosenfe/soc_meth_proj3/matrix_OLS_NYU_notes.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emrosenfe/soc_meth_proj3/matrix_OLS_NYU_notes.pdf)) if we could just do

$$  X\hat\beta = Y $$
$$  X'X\hat\beta = X'Y $$
$$  \hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$$

what am I missing?

Comment: Hi: you just showed that if $Y = X \hat{\beta}$, then $\hat{\beta} = (X^{\prime}X)^{-1}X^{\prime} Y$. This is true but it doesn't prove that the sum of squares of the residuals from the regression are minimized.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'm wondering why do we need to think about the residuals if this is true. The way I think about it is that if we want to get some weights (beta) that together with predictors (X) form the outcome (Y), then we can get these betas like this. Where is the room for minimizing the residuals (or any kind of estimation really) in that if that relationship always holds?

Comment: The system can't be solved exactly because it's overdetermined (there are more equations than unknowns). As such, we need to define what it means for $\hat{\beta}}$ to be a solution. One intuitive way to pick a beta is to choose it so it minimizes the squared sum of residuals. But there are other ways to do so.

Comment: @PetrP: you can get the weights ( better to think of the weights as $\hat{\beta}$ ) that way. but you're not proving anything about the properties of that estimate in your initial statement. All you are saying is how you get them. I could say that my $\hat{\beta}  = $ your $\hat{\beta} - 1 $. Why is your $\hat{\beta}$ better than mine ?

Comment: For example, I could say that I want the median of the residuals to be minimized. That would result in a different $\hat{\beta}$. The resulting $\hat{\beta}$  is dependent on the loss function used. Classical OLS uses minimization of the sum of the squared residuals as the criteria which results in the squared loss function. Your statement does not show this.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation is misleading. Initially, either $X\beta = E[Y]$ or $X\hat \beta = \hat Y$. The orthogonal decomposition that allows $Y = \hat Y + e $ stems from minimizing the square residuals.
$$
X \hat \beta = X( Y + e) = XY + Xe = XY, 
$$
it stems from the fact that the residuals $e$ are orthogonal to the space spanned by $X$. Although now you can proceed with your derivation, but it is based on the decomposition that is obtained from the residual minimization in the first place.